# PIVOT Table Order of Operations

Tags: sql-server, pivot, operator-precedence

Can anyone tell me the order of evaluation / operation / execution for a PIVOT statement in MS SQL 2014 ?  In other words what are the general steps taken by SQL to arrive at the pivoted output given the code below? This would include the SELECT, INTO, FROM and PIVOT clauses.

```
WITH NumberShipsCTE2 AS

(
SELECT
    ShipperID -- grouping / column 
    , CustID -- spreading / rows
    , OrderID
    , 1 AS AggCol -- aggregation column
FROM Sales.Orders
) 

SELECT CustId, [1], [2], [3]
INTO Sales.NumberShipsTBL
FROM NumberShipsCTE2
PIVOT(COUNT(OrderID) FOR ShipperId IN ([1],[2],[3]) ) AS X;
```

Based on the TSQL2012 database.

Note I have a pretty good understanding how CTEs work and I am not looking for an explanation on this function.

Comment: See if the 'Using Pivot and Unpivot' section in this doc helps: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Links as answers are frowned upon so I'll leave this as a comment :) http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you and the later article http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-clause-and-pivot might help

Comment: I don't know if this is legal, but I would like to highlight http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-clause-and-pivot)